# Vuelidate - как мне применить правила валидации для каждого объекта отдельно?

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Есть у меня форма с полями и $each применяет правила валидации для всех объектов fields, но я хочу указать разные поля первому, второму, третьему объектам, как мне это сделать?

Пробовал разные варианты и ничего не работает, инфу как-то по этому поводу тоже найти не могу...

```
 <template v-for="v in $v.fields.$each.$iter">
          <a-col :key="v.$model.id" class="form-item">
            <a-form-item
              :has-feedback="v.value.$error"
              :validate-status="v.value.$error ? 'error' : ''"
              :label="v.$model.name"
              :help="v.value.$error && getErrorMessage(v.value)"
            >
              <a-input
                v-model.trim="v.value.$model"
                :placeholder="v.$model.placeholder"
              />
            </a-form-item>
          </a-col>
        </template>
```

```
data: () => ({
    fields: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Имя пользователя",
        placeholder: "Введите логин пользователя",
        createclientname: "name",
        value: "",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Пароль",
        placeholder: "Введите пароль",
        createclientname: "password",
        value: "",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Почта",
        placeholder: "Введите почту",
        createclientname: "email",
        value: "",
      },
    ],

    fieldRole: "DEALER_ADMIN",
  }),
  validations: {
    fields: {
      required,
      $each: {
        value: {
          required,
        },
      },
    },
  }
```